# CSS Change outline colour of button

Tags: html, css

Pretty new to CSS and i just want to change the defualt outline colour of a button. I beleive im using bootstrap

So far i can change the button colour when the mouse hovers over it, and also the default text colour but not the outline

Ive tried this

```
.btn-outline-info{
color: #ea4335;
outline-color: #ea4335;
}
```

the color part works but the outline-color does not

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try border-color

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.btn-outline-info {
  color: blue;
  border-color: red;
}
.btn-outline-info:hover {
  color: green;
  border-color: purple;
}
</style>

<button class="btn btn-outline-info">Info</button>
```

Comment: While the other answers discuss how to change `outline` style, I voted for this one because `border` is the more correct property to be leveraging.  `border` is presentational and tied to the box model.  While `outline` _could_ be used in a presentational manner, it is [generally leveraged for accessibility purposes (showing focus) in the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline#Accessibility_concerns), so you have to be a bit more mindful about when and why you alter it from its default setting.

Comment: [@haz14](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10581872/haz14) did this solve your question? If so please mark is as answer or let me know if you have more questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add an outline style. For example,

outline-style: solid;
outline-color: #92a8d1;

Answer (score 0):

```
.btn:active {
 outline-color: red;
}
```

:active is when the button is being hovered

Comment: `:active` would be when the button is being actively pressed. `:hover` would be for hover.

Answer (score 0):

This adds the outline style and color on focus:

```
.btn-outline-info:focus {
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-color: #ea4335;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS it's important to remember that like in HTML and javascript, the computer won't do what you want it to do, it only does what it has to do. It doesn't know what the CSS property outline-colour is, so it does nothing.

Do make an outline of a button, you use `border-color: (color)`. Or you could add a specified border using, `border: 3px solid green;` there are many changes you can make with borders. To have a full explanation, head to the W3 schools site. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border.asp

And then on hover, you could do this,

```
button:hover {
  border: 2px dotted blue;
  color: purple; 
}
```

Also In the future, this kind of question doesn't need a whole discussion on stack overflow, it can be easily researched and troubleshooted!

Cheers